# accessing the values of collections.defaultdict

Tags: python, csv

I have a csv file that I want to read column wise, for that I've this code :

```
from collections import  defaultdict
from csv import DictReader

columnwise_table = defaultdict(list)
with open("Weird_stuff.csv",'rU') as f:
    reader = DictReader(f)
    for row in reader:
        for col,dat in row.items():
            columnwise_table[col].append(dat)
#print(columnwise_table.items())  # this gives me everything 

print(type(columnwise_table[2]) # I'm look for smt like this
```

my question is how can get all the element of only one specific column ? and I'm not using conda and the matrix is big 2400x980

**UPDATE**

I have 980 columns and over 2000 rows  I need to work with the file using the columns say  1st column[0]: `feature1` 2nd column[0]: `j_ss01` 50th column:`Abs2`  and so on
 since I can't access the dict using the column names I would like to use an index for that. is this possible ?

Comment: Did you try: `columnwise_table[col_name]`?

Comment: Well I can't  since the names are randomly generated(not numbers)

Comment: How do you mean names are randomly generated? Aren't you reading those from the file.

Comment: yes the file itself is generated from a program  the names are generated from this program and do not have a sense

Comment: Could you give a better example of what you want than `type(col_table[2])`? So far, you've said that you get a csv with random field names and you want to specifically get all of the values for a column that you have no idea how to reference because it's random. If you did this by hand, how would you know which column to choose?

Comment: Use `csv.reader` which will return each row as a `list` of values. If you want the particular value simply use the column number it is in. i.e.: `columnwise_table[col].append(row[2])` would append column number 3 from each row read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import csv
import collections

col_values = collections.defaultdict(list)
with open('Wierd_stuff.csv', 'rU') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    # skip field names
    next(reader)
    for row in csv.reader(f):
        for col, value in enumerate(row):
            col_values[col].append(value)

# for each numbered column you want...
col_index = 33  # for example
print(col_values[col_index])
```

If you know the columns you want in advance, only storing those columns could save you some space...

```
cols = set(1, 5, 6, 234)

...
        for col, value in enumerate(row):
            if col in cols:
                col_values[col].append(value)
```

Answer (score 1):

By iterating on row.items, you get all columns.

If you want only one specific column via index number, use `csv.reader` and column index instead.

```
from csv import reader

col_values = []
# Column index number to get values from
col = 1

with open("Weird_stuff.csv",'rU') as f:
    reader = reader(f)
    for row in reader:
        col_val = row[col]
        col_values.append(col_val)

# contains only values from column index <col>
print(col_values)
```

Comment: `DictReader` uses the values of the first line as column names unless different names are supplied  by `fieldnames`. If column names are not known, `DictReader` is not appropriate and should use `csv.reader` and col index instead per suggestion above. Would help if you showed a sample of the csv.